# Pyspark dataframe: Count elements in array or list

Tags: arrays, list, dataframe, pyspark, counting

Let us assume dataframe `df` as:

```
df.show()
```

Output:

```
+------+----------------+
|letter| list_of_numbers|
+------+----------------+
|     A|    [3, 1, 2, 3]|
|     B|    [1, 2, 1, 1]|
+------+----------------+
```

What I want to do is to `count` number of a specific element in column `list_of_numbers`. Something like this:

```
+------+----------------+----+
|letter| list_of_numbers|ones|
+------+----------------+----+
|     A|    [3, 1, 2, 3]|   1|
|     B|    [1, 2, 1, 1]|   3|
+------+----------------+----+
```

I have so far tried creating `udf` and it perfectly works, but I'm wondering if I can do it without defining any `udf`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can explode the array and filter the exploded values for `1`. Then `groupBy` and `count`:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, count, explode

df.select("*", explode("list_of_numbers").alias("exploded"))\
    .where(col("exploded") == 1)\
    .groupBy("letter", "list_of_numbers")\
    .agg(count("exploded").alias("ones"))\
    .show()
#+------+---------------+----+
#|letter|list_of_numbers|ones|
#+------+---------------+----+
#|     A|   [3, 1, 2, 3]|   1|
#|     B|   [1, 2, 1, 1]|   3|
#+------+---------------+----+
```

---

In order to keep all rows, even when the count is 0, you can convert the `exploded` column into an indicator variable. Then `groupBy` and `sum`.

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, count, explode, sum as sum_

df.select("*", explode("list_of_numbers").alias("exploded"))\
    .withColumn("exploded", (col("exploded") == 1).cast("int"))\
    .groupBy("letter", "list_of_numbers")\
    .agg(sum_("exploded").alias("ones"))\
    .show()
```

Note, I have imported `pyspark.sql.functions.sum` as `sum_` as to not overwrite the builtin `sum` function.

Comment: Nice! This works, by considering the fact that I should `join` the result with original `df`. Otherwise I lose those rows without `one` :)

Comment: @AllaTarighati, I have posted an update for that case so you can avoid a join back with the original df.

Answer (score 5):

From pyspark 3+, we can use array transformations.

https://mungingdata.com/spark-3/array-exists-forall-transform-aggregate-zip_with/
https://medium.com/expedia-group-tech/deep-dive-into-apache-spark-array-functions-720b8fbfa729

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = spark_session.createDataFrame(
    [
        ['A',[3, 1, 2, 3]],
        ['B',[1, 2, 1, 1]]
    ],      
        ['letter','list_of_numbers'])

df1 = df.selectExpr('*','filter(list_of_numbers, x->x=1) as ones_array')
df2 = df1.selectExpr('*', 'size(ones_array) as ones')
df2.show()

+------+---------------+----------+----+
|letter|list_of_numbers|ones_array|ones|
+------+---------------+----------+----+
|     A|   [3, 1, 2, 3]|       [1]|   1|
|     B|   [1, 2, 1, 1]| [1, 1, 1]|   3|
+------+---------------+----------+----+
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that the length of the list is constant, one way i can think of is,

```py
from operator import add
from functools import reduce
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = sql.createDataFrame(
    [
        ['A',[3, 1, 2, 3]],
        ['B',[1, 2, 1, 1]]
    ],      
        ['letter','list_of_numbers'])

expr = reduce(add,[F.when(F.col('list_of_numbers').getItem(x)==1, 1)\
                    .otherwise(0) for x in range(4)])
df = df.withColumn('ones', expr)
df.show()

+------+---------------+----+
|letter|list_of_numbers|ones|
+------+---------------+----+
|     A|   [3, 1, 2, 3]|   1|
|     B|   [1, 2, 1, 1]|   3|
+------+---------------+----+
```

Comment: Thank you, but they do not necessarily have same size.

Answer (score 0):

There was a comment above from Ala Tarighati that the solution did not work for arrays with different lengths. The following is a udf that will solve that problem

```
from operator import add
from functools import reduce
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = sql.createDataFrame(
    [
        ['A',[3, 1, 2, 3]],
        ['B',[1, 2, 1, 1]]
    ],      
        ['letter','list_of_numbers'])

df_ones = (
    df.withColumn(
        'ones', 
        reduce(
            add,
            [
                F.when(
                    F.col("list_of_numbers").getItem(x) == F.lit("1"), 1
                ).otherwise(0)
                for x in range(len("drivers"))
            ],
        ),
    )
)
df_ones.show()
+------+---------------+----+
|letter|list_of_numbers|ones|
+------+---------------+----+
|     A|   [3, 1, 2, 3]|   1|
|     B|   [1, 2, 1, 1]|   3|
+------+---------------+----+
```